# Unable to locate wordpress content directory (wp-content)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have configured my wordpress (5.0.3 -- latest) on the remote server (OS: Ubuntu 18.04).

Please find the directory structure for my blog directory. As you would notice, permissions are there so that `wp-content` is writable.

[image]

Following is the configuration in my `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'ssh2' );
define( 'FTP_BASE', '/var/www/html/blog/' );
define( 'FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/' );
define( 'FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins/' );

define( 'FTP_USER', 'ubuntu' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'XXXXXX' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'www.mydomain.com:22' );
define( 'FTP_SSL', true );
```

Now, when I'm trying to do any kind of write (like editing post, adding a theme, etc. I'm facing the error: "unable to locate wordpress content directory (wp-content)" while it is properly defined.

Another strange thing I noticed, while I was uploading the theme, it happened successfully in `wp-content/uploads`, but nothing new gets installed. Help me resolve this issue, as I have deployed wp before couple of times but this issue is something very new to me. All of the solutions available tell me to set that `CONTENT_DIR` in `wp-config.php`, which I have done from the very beginning anyway.

Comment: To avoid all these kind of problems, I am creating a group www on the server and add www-data and all FTP-Users to that group. Then I set everything to that group and 0775. Works fine.

Comment: @WolfgangBlessen But you can see, owner of the project is `ubuntu`, and FTP credentials are also of `ubuntu`. (See config)

Comment: Then search for "unable to locate wordpress content directory (wp-content)" in the WordPress Source and log or echo the path, WP is trying to open.

Comment: Yes, I see ubuntu is owner, but WP is running with www-data.